# Top hat laser beam

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, laser

Could you obtain a Gaussian profile from a square tophat laser beam?
If yes what optics should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [spatial filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_filter) or "beam cleaning" setup: focus the beam on a very small pinhole to eliminate all modes other than the fundamental TEM$_{00}$ (Gaussian).

You will end up throwing away most of the beam's intensity, but if that's not a concern then this is a simple low-cost solution.

Comment: If the loss is acceptable, this method also has the advantage of outputting a zero aberration beam, as the pinhole needs to be subresolvable to make this work. This method yields the reference beam for a point diffraction interferometer, for example.

Answer (score 3):

With for example a neutral-density filter such as these https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1163

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want to do with the light afterwards. If you require low aberration wavefronts, then you're pretty much confined to [Lasper's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/304604/26076).

Otherwise, if wavefront quality is not important (as in some illumination applications), you can use aspheric surfaces to redistribute the intensity as a function of radius. This is sometimes done to make Gaussian beams into flat tops, but the inverse is of course done to a flat top beam input to the output of such a lens. See:

D. Shafer, "Gaussian to flat-top intensity distributing lens", *Optics & Laser Technology*, **14**, #3 1982

Google / DuckDuckGo on "aspheric intensity distribution" (separate terms, not in quotes) and this will bring you other articles.